# Client_id is invalid even if I set the client_id

Tags: asp.net-core, openiddict

Okay so full story is that I am trying to set up an api with no frontend as our clients will be integrating with our endpoint. So I wanted to make an api with a simple OAuth 3.1 and the api is aspnetcore 3.1.

I followed the sample Matty and Velusia but wasnt getting anywhere. and most of the examples like the one found here https://kevinchalet.com/2017/01/30/implementing-simple-token-authentication-in-aspnet-core-with-openiddict/

Are what I want but for a different version.

Essentially tldr; I am trying to get an api that requires other clients to send username and password along with clientid and secret to my token endpoint and then they can hit any or some of my endpoints as long as they provide the bearer token. Thats it nothing else, but I am struggling with that.

Below you will find the error I am currently getting along with my code.

After going through the steps I find I can run the application but in postman I continue to get the error

```
{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "The specified 'client_id' is invalid.",
    "error_uri": "https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2052"
}
```

in post man i am using this cURL

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://localhost:44388/connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'username=username' \
--data-urlencode 'password=password' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=postmantestclient' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=myclientsecret'
```

and my startup.cs is as follows.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting; 
using OpenIddict.Abstractions;
using Quartz;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
    public class Startup
        {
            public Startup(IConfiguration configuration,IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
            {
                Configuration = configuration;
                WebHostEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
            }
    
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public IWebHostEnvironment WebHostEnvironment { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddTransient(o => new MYApiContext(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")));
            // Register the OpenIddict services.
            // Note: use the generic overload if you need
            // to replace the default OpenIddict entities.
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<FulfillmentApiContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders(); 
            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                // Configure Identity to use the same JWT claims as OpenIddict instead
                // of the legacy WS-Federation claims it uses by default (ClaimTypes),
                // which saves you from doing the mapping in your authorization controller.
                options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = Claims.Name;
                options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = Claims.Subject;
                options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = Claims.Role;
                options.ClaimsIdentity.EmailClaimType = Claims.Email;

                // Note: to require account confirmation before login,
                // register an email sender service (IEmailSender) and
                // set options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount to true.
                //
                // For more information, visit https://aka.ms/aspaccountconf.
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
            });

            // OpenIddict offers native integration with Quartz.NET to perform scheduled tasks
            // (like pruning orphaned authorizations/tokens from the database) at regular intervals.
            services.AddQuartz(options =>
            {
                options.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();
                options.UseSimpleTypeLoader();
                options.UseInMemoryStore();
            });

            // Register the Quartz.NET service and configure it to block shutdown until jobs are complete.
            services.AddQuartzHostedService(options => options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true); 
            services.AddOpenIddict()
            .AddCore(options =>
            {
                //Use EF integration pass to OpenIddict tha database is used by ASP.NET Identity stores
                options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
                .UseDbContext<MYApiContext>()
                .ReplaceDefaultEntities<MYApiContext.ApplicationClient, MYApiContext.ApplicationAuthorization, MYApiContext.ApplicationScope, MYApiContext.ApplicationToken, long>();
            }).AddServer(options =>
            {
                //// Enable the device, verification, token and userinfo endpoints.
                //options.SetDeviceEndpointUris("/connect/authorize")
                //       .SetVerificationEndpointUris("/connect/logout")
                //       .SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token")
                //       .SetUserinfoEndpointUris("/connect/userinfo");
                options.SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token");
                // Mark the "email", "profile" and "roles" scopes as supported scopes.
                options.RegisterScopes(OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Email, OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Profile, OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Roles);


                // Note: this sample only uses the authorization code flow but you can enable
                // the other flows if you need to support implicit, password or client credentials.
                //options.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow();
                //options.AllowClientCredentialsFlow();
                options.AllowPasswordFlow();
                //options.AcceptAnonymousClients();
                // Register the signing and encryption credentials.
                options.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate()
                       .AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();

                // Register the ASP.NET Core host and configure the ASP.NET Core-specific options.
                options.UseAspNetCore()
                       .EnableLogoutEndpointPassthrough()
                       .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
                       .EnableUserinfoEndpointPassthrough()
                       .EnableStatusCodePagesIntegration();
            }).AddValidation(options =>
            {
                options.SetClientId("postmantestclient");
                options.SetClientSecret("myclientsecret");
                options.UseLocalServer();
                options.UseAspNetCore();
            });
            // Register the OpenIddict validation components.
            //.AddValidation(options =>
            //{
            //    // Import the configuration from the local OpenIddict server instance.
            //    options.UseLocalServer();

            //    // Register the ASP.NET Core host.
            //    options.UseAspNetCore();

            //    options.AddEventHandler<OpenIddictValidationEvents.ProcessAuthenticationContext>(builder =>
            //    {
            //        builder.UseInlineHandler(context =>
            //        {
            //            var request = context.Transaction.GetHttpRequest();
            //            Debug.WriteLine("Authorization header: {0}", request.Headers.Authorization.ToString());

            //            return default;
            //        });

            //        builder.SetOrder(ExtractAccessTokenFromAuthorizationHeader.Descriptor.Order + 1);
            //    });
            //});
            //services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(o => o.UserSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"))); 
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            } 
            //app.UseOpenIdConnectServer
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

my authenticationController is as follows

```
public class AuthorizationController:BaseControllerClass
    {

        private readonly IOpenIddictApplicationManager _applicationManager;
        private readonly IOpenIddictAuthorizationManager _authorizationManager;
        private readonly IOpenIddictScopeManager _scopeManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public AuthorizationController(
            IOpenIddictApplicationManager applicationManager,
            IOpenIddictAuthorizationManager authorizationManager,
            IOpenIddictScopeManager scopeManager,
            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _applicationManager = applicationManager;
            _authorizationManager = authorizationManager;
            _scopeManager = scopeManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }
 [HttpPost("~/connect/token"), Produces("application/json")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Exchange(OpenIddictRequest request)
        { 
            if (request.IsPasswordGrantType())
            { 
                // Validate the user credentials.
                // Note: to mitigate brute force attacks, you SHOULD strongly consider
                // applying a key derivation function like PBKDF2 to slow down
                // the password validation process. You SHOULD also consider
                // using a time-constant comparer to prevent timing attacks.
                if (request.Username != "alice@wonderland.com" ||
                    request.Password != "P@ssw0rd")
                {
                    return Forbid(OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                }
                // Create a new ClaimsIdentity holding the user identity.
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                    OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Name,
                    OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Role);
                // Add a "sub" claim containing the user identifier, and attach
                // the "access_token" destination to allow OpenIddict to store it
                // in the access token, so it can be retrieved from your controllers.
                identity.AddClaim(OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Subject,
                    "71346D62-9BA5-4B6D-9ECA-755574D628D8",
                    OpenIddictConstants.Destinations.AccessToken);
                identity.AddClaim(OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Name, "Alice",
                    OpenIddictConstants.Destinations.AccessToken);
                // ... add other claims, if necessary.
                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                // Ask OpenIddict to generate a new token and return an OAuth2 token response.
                return SignIn(principal, OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            }
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The specified grant type is not supported.");
        }

}
```

and my dataContext class is as follows

```
public class MYApiContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString;
        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>();
            modelBuilder.UseOpenIddict<ApplicationClient, ApplicationAuthorization, ApplicationScope, ApplicationToken, long>();
            //modelBuilder.RemovePluralizingTableNameConvention();
        } 
        public MYApiContext (string connectionString)
        {
            _connectionString = connectionString;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connectionString);
        }

        public class ApplicationClient : OpenIddictEntityFrameworkCoreApplication<long, ApplicationAuthorization, ApplicationToken>
        {

            public bool IsActive { get; set; }
            public string Remarks { get; set; }
        }

        public class ApplicationAuthorization :OpenIddictEntityFrameworkCoreAuthorization<long, ApplicationClient, ApplicationToken> { }
        public class ApplicationScope : OpenIddictEntityFrameworkCoreScope<long> { }
        public class ApplicationToken : OpenIddictEntityFrameworkCoreToken<long, ApplicationClient, ApplicationAuthorization> { }
 
    }
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. I am new to the core and DI. Any good places to read up on DI and Core would also be helpful

Comment: ASP.Net Core : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/introduction-to-clean-architecture-and-implementation-with-asp-net-core/

.Net Core with Web API: https://www.toptal.com/asp-dot-net/asp-net-web-api-tutorial

DI in .Net Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: exclude client_id and client_secret from postman request.

Comment: @Nayan if i do that then I get this error {
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "The mandatory 'client_id' parameter is missing.",
    "error_uri": "https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2029"
}

Comment: Does options.AcceptAnonymousClients(); in startup.cs working?

Comment: Here is some sample reference with demo implementation

https://nwb.one/blog/openid-connect-dotnet-5

Comment: @Nayan That demo looks like its sending me in the right direction. Let me try that real fast and see what happens. But my question is why is it dotnet-5 instead of core3.1?

Comment: @Nayan Okay that blog post worked. Although I cant seem to get the refresh token but either way the missing piece was step 8. Not sure how i would have ever come up with that. Thanks.

What do you recommend I do to make sure each client_id and secret is unique per customer. And how should I create new customers without creating a Register Controller?

Comment: Here is the article with flow including refresh tokens.
https://dev.to/robinvanderknaap/setting-up-an-authorization-server-with-openiddict-part-i-introduction-4jid